Equality regarding score function
I'm reading Bogetoft and Otto (2011) page 249 and this equality regarding the score function stumped me:
$Var\Big[- \Big(\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2}\Big)^{-1} \frac{\partial l}{\partial\beta}\Big] = E\Big[\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2}\Big]^{-2} Var\Big[\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}\Big]$
How would one prove this? These are the properties of $\frac{\partial l}{\partial\beta}$ that I know of:
$E\Big[\frac{\partial l}{\partial\beta}\Big] = 0$
$Var\Big[\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta}\Big] = -E\Big[\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \beta^2}\Big] = J$
where $J$ is the information matrix.
The way its written makes it look like it's a simple deduction but I must have some fundamental misconception about score functions. Any help appreciated.
